# Buggy daily reputation counting when various costs are involved?

Tags: support, reputation

Below you can find [my reputations for yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/users/750378/daveball-aka-user750378?tab=reputation#page_1-view_time). Can someone tell me whether it's buggy - or explain me this very strange behavior?

1. +200 from over 20 upvotes ([for my cowboy pic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398703/linked-list-loop-detection-algorithm/7398882#7398882) ;), which is OK due to daily limit
2. +149 due to a down-vote I made and a bounty I started
3. not going above +149 even though I got further upvotes :(
4. +147 due to a down-vote I got
5. +149 from further up-votes :-0

---

So are different costs treated differently? The faq only says "You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day" and I couldn't find anything relevant for my case of bounty costs here on meta either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get reputation lost due to your own downvotes back...as this would make them effectively free for high-daily-rep users that cap often.  This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: Ok, thanks (+1). So own downvotes and bounty-costs should not be free for high-daily-rep users, but getting downvotes should be free since high-daily-rep users are usually competent and not spammers.

Comment: Just as a suggestion: In my opinion, stating this fact in a one-time warning when starting a bounty when you've reached +200 rep would increase stackexchange's usability.